# Posting to WebMethod with ajax error

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, web-services, webmethod

**Step1:**

I have defined my script as: on `home.aspx` page:

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    var post = ({
        method: "POST",
        url: "home.aspx/GetData",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: { name: "Mobile" },
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        success: function (data) {
            alert("here" + data.d.toString());
            alert(data.d);
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
}
```

**Step2:**

Call to the script function from button: it's on `home.aspx` page:

```
<input id="btnGetTime" type="button" value="Show Current Time" onclick="ShowCurrentTime()" />
```

**Step3:**

Defined Web method at `home.aspx.cs` page:

```
[System.Web.Services.WebMethod]
public static string GetData(string name)
{
    return "Welcome";
}
```

I am getting:

> JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'd' of undefined or
>   null reference

Comment: It would be better if you can include which statement raises the errro

Comment: alert("here" + data.d.toString());
This Line Responsible for error.

Comment: What's in you `<head>` tags? Are you including the proper jQuery libraries for your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to stringify your data:

```
data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Mobile" })
```

And use ajax like this:

```
$.ajax({ ... });
```

Full script updated:

```
function ShowCurrentTime() {
    $.ajax({
        method: "POST",
        url: "home.aspx/GetData",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify({ name: "Mobile" }),
        contentType: "application/json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert("here" + data.d.toString());
            alert(data.d);
        },
        failure: function() {
            alert("Fail");
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Why this error occure:
JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'd' of undefined or null reference

Comment: Which version of jQuery are you using? Can you show the full aspx page?

Answer (score -1):

Try this and tell me if it work :

```
<script type = "text/javascript">
                function ShowCurrentTime() {
                 var post = ({
                            method: "POST",
                            url: "home.aspx/GetData",
                            dataType: 'json',
                            data: { name: "Mobile" },
                            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                      success: function (data) {
                          alert("here" + data.d.toString());
                              alert(data.d);},
                      failure: function() {
                          alert("Fail");}
                             });
                }
                </script>
```